# SQL server shows different versions when seen from about screen and from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, version

I had to see version of my sql server management studio, I went to Help --> About, it showed me following screen:

link to image: [About Screen of my SQL Server Management Studio](http://oi59.tinypic.com/33vix4o.jpg)

It clearly shows that SQL Server is R2 with version 10.50.1600.1.

But when I run query 
Select @@version, It returns me this:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (Intel X86)   Mar 29 2009 10:27:29   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 5.1  (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)

Which shows it is not R2, also version is changes i.e 10.0.2531.0

I am not getting why is this? Can someone explain why both enquiries return different versions. Although I installed R2 in it.

And if it is not R2 then how to upgrade it to R2. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see version of SQL Server on local computer by using `Help\About`. but when run `select @@Version`, you see version of SQL Server database engine that login on it. In other word you run SSMS from local computer and `Help\About` show version of SSMS. and then login to sql server database engine of your server, `Select @@Version` show version of sql server on the server.

Comment: Oh I see, now can you please tell how can I upgrade my sql server database engine from 10.0.2531.0 to 10.50.1600.1?

Comment: you must install sql server Service pack. `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437`

Comment: I've installed but still it is returning me following result:

**Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (Intel X86)   Mar 29 2009 10:27:29   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 5.1 <X86> (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)**

Comment: @annycca. Install service pack on the server or on your client?

Comment: I have downloaded from your link and installed. Now how to check if it is being installed on client or server? But I guess I am installing on server, :/

Comment: I suggest that install again in your server and check again your version.